# mocha - chai-http returns status 500

Tags: mocha.js, sequelize.js, chai, chai-http

I'm running tests on a JavaScript CRUD application with Mocha, Chai, and Chai HTTP.  The application uses Sequelize.  All the tested functions GET and POST properly in the browser.  However, all my tests are failing with a status 500.  When I tried to GET routes not included in my app, I got 404 statuses, so I'm pretty sure the server is hooked up properly to the tests.  Any ideas?

Here's the test suite:

```js
//test suite for user controller


process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const server = require('../server');
const should = chai.should();
const models = require('../models');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

chai.use(chaiHttp);

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    this.setDate(this.getDate() + parseInt(days));
    return this;
};

let currentDate = new Date();

describe('Users', function() {
  beforeEach('clear and add', function(done) {
    let newUser = {
      email: 'susan@example.com',
      password: 'spaz5713'
    }
 models.User.sync({ force: true })
 .then(function() {
  return models.User
  .create(newUser)
  .then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
  });
 });
    let newSession = {
      sid: 'WDfAv8WICmE_gyrEjckhG_a9ijWNekZD',
      data: '"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":259200000,"expires":"' + currentDate.addDays(3) + '","httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"email":"susan@example.com","password":"' + bcrypt.hashSync("spaz5713", bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)) + '"'
    }
    models.ConnectSession.sync({force: true})
    .then(function() {
      return models.ConnectSession
      .create(newSession)
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        done();
      });
    });
  });

  it('should render the landing page', function(done) {
    chai.request(server)
    .get('/')
    .end(function(err, res) {
      console.log(res);
      res.should.have.status(200);
      res.should.be.html;
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should get signup page /user/signup GET', function(done) {
    chai.request(server)
    .get('/user/signup')
    .end(function(err, res) {
      console.log(res);
      res.should.have.status(200);
      done();
    });
  });

 it('should create new user /user/signup POST', function(done) {
     let newUser = {
       'email': 'alice@example.com',
       'password': 'spaz5713'
     }
    chai.request(server)
     .post('/user/signup')
     .send(newUser)
     .end(function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
       res.should.have.status(200);
       done();
     });
   });
    
    //etc
   });
```

Here's my server:

```js
// ++++++ dev tools ++++++
const util = require('util');


// ++++++ General Express config ++++++
const express         = require('express'),
      bodyParser      = require('body-parser'),
      logger          = require('morgan'),
   hbs     = require('express-handlebars'),
      cookieParser    = require('cookie-parser'),
      app             = express(),
   routes     = require('./routes/index');

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static("./public"));

//++++++ Handlebars config ++++++
app.engine('hbs', hbs({
  extname: 'hbs',
  defaultLayout: 'main',
  layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/',
  partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials/'
}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

//++++++ express sessions ++++++
const session  = require('express-session'),
database     = require('./models').sequelize,
SequelStore    = require('connect-sequelize')(session),
secret      = require('./config/secret'),
modelName    = 'ConnectSession';

app.use(session({
  secret: secret,
  store: new SequelStore(database, {}, modelName),
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

//++++++ Routes ++++++
app.use(routes);

// ++++++ SERVER LISTEN ++++++
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const server = app.listen(PORT, function () {
  const host = server.address().address;
  const port = server.address().port;
  console.log('express server listening to your mom at http://' + host + ':' + port);
});

module.exports = server;
```

Comment: found the problem!  the handlebars section of the server needed this line: `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');`  no idea why it worked in the browser without that.